# CORS issue using create-react-app when trying to use an image from another URL

Tags: reactjs, cors, create-react-app

I normally create my react projects with a static express server but figured I would give create-react-app a shot.

However I am running into an issue with my current project. 
When trying to use an img tag in the react code and use the src URL from another site I get a CORS issue.

"Access to image at 'http://www.dailygarnish.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/IMG_20120414_205845-640x640.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

This works perfectly fine normally on Apps where I created the server, but not with create-react-app

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: This is a configuration from the server that is hosting the image, to solve this you should allow your server to receive cross-origin requests from the react app. If it's not your server there is nothing you can do about it

Comment: I tested the same image URL in another react app on my local machine and it displayed correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in your package.json, and then restart CRA dev server(must be done):

```
"proxy": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
```

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't work in my package.json, but I checked out the docs for cors-anywhere and put the image url after it: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/imageUrlHere in the img tag src and then it displays correctly.

Comment: Well yes. I've been using it to surpass CORS problems with some third party public APIs too. You can simply prepend API url with corseverywhere url and it could be solved. Glad it works!